# how to: rails base validation view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As mentioned [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#errors-base)

> You can add error messages that are related to the object's state as a
>   whole, instead of being related to a specific attribute. You can use
>   this method when you want to say that the object is invalid, no matter
>   the values of its attributes. Since errors[:base] is an array, you can
>   simply add a string to it and it will be used as an error message.
>
> ```
> class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
>   def a_method_used_for_validation_purposes
>     errors[:base] << "This person is invalid because ..."
>   end
> ```

My validation actually works but it does not automatically display an error message. Here is what I've got:

```
  def free_plan_can_only_have_one_room
    if self.new_record? && (tenant.rooms.count > 0) && (tenant.plan == 'free')
      errors.add(:base, "Free plans cannot have more than 1 room")
    end
  end
```

Any Ideas how to create the view for the error?

My view:

```
= simple_form_for @room, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.input :name
  = f.association :office
  = f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary'
  = link_to 'Back to all rooms', rooms_path, :class => 'btn btn-default'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing something like this code somewhere at the top of the page or wherever you want you error to be shown:

```
<% @room.errors.values.each do |error_messages| %>
  <% error_messages.each do |message| %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
      <%== message %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```